# Callback on recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, requestjs

The following code is used to fetch a `.zip` file from our web application. The file is generated by closing another application safely then zipping, finally sending it for download.

```
var dl = function() {
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'some_url',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Scripted-Download'
        },
        encoding: null,
        jar: true
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) throw(err)
        if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/zip;charset=utf-8') {
            process.stdout.write('\rDownloading file ..')
            var id = uuid.v4()
            , file = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../' + id + '.zip')
            fs.writeFile(file, body, function(err) {
                if (err) throw(err)
                process.stdout.write('\rFile downloaded ' + id + '.zip')
                process.exit(0)
            })
        } else {
            process.stdout.write('\rAwaiting file ..')
            setTimeout(dl(), 30 * 1000)
        }
    })
}
```

This works as expected. However, I need to use this from another script. So the above code returns an `id` of the file downloaded, then from another script I can extract the `.zip` and place the extracted files into a directory with the same `id`. These files would then be made available to download.

**EDIT** Essentially I need to execute this script, extract the contents when it's downloaded then load a UI with `res.render()` when the previous two steps are complete. This needs to be done with an `id` so that two users don't create conflicting files.

Comment: What is the difficulty you're having ? Extract in node to a folder exposed to `http` ?

Comment: I need to know that the file has been downloaded. Otherwise the user will be trying to download a file which doesn't exist which would produce a 404.

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**

Comment: I think you're looking for a promise then.

Comment: That had crossed my mind, could you provide a promised version of the above?

Comment: It's just a promise, you can look them up but basically `fs.writeFile(file, body, function(err) {
            if (err) reject(err)
            resolve(' + id + '.zip');
        })` should do.

Comment: Trying to promisify the above results in `TypeError: first._onTimeout is not a function`

Comment: Where's the recursion?

Comment: You surely want `setTimeout(aspectDownload, 30 * 1000)` not `setTimeout(aspectDownload(), 30 * 1000)`

Comment: Apologies, please see update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, promises should make this easy. First promisify the async functionality you need:

```
function makeRequest(parameters) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(parameters,  function (err, res, body) {
            if (err) { reject (err); }
            else { resolve({ res: res, body: body }); }
        });
    });
}

function writeFile(file, body) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.writeFile(file, body, function(err) {
            if (err) { reject(err); }
            else { resolve(); }
        });
    });
}

function timeout(duration) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, duration);
    });
}
```

Then use them.

```
var dl = function () {
    return makeRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'some_url',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Scripted-Download'
        },
        encoding: null,
        jar: true
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (result.res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/zip;charset=utf-8') {
            process.stdout.write('\rDownloading file ..')
            var id = uuid.v4()
            , file = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../' + id + '.zip');

            return writeFile(file, result.body)
                .then(function () { return id; });
        } else {
            process.stdout.write('\rAwaiting file ..');

            return timeout(30 * 1000).then(dl);
        }
    });
}

dl().then(function (id) { process.stdout.write('\rid is: ' + id); });
```

Comment: Where is `aspectDownload` defined?

Comment: @KarlBateman You tell me. You just edited it out of your own question 16 mintues ago. Updated my answer to match the current state of your question.

Comment: Ah, yes I thought that's what it referred to. After copying your answer and adding the correct url I am getting the following error `TypeError: first._onTimeout is not a function`

Comment: @KarlBateman I had the parameters backwards in the `setTimeout` call of my `timeout` function. Could you take my updated code and try again?

Comment: The message `Downloading file ..` never finishes even though the file is downloaded?

Comment: @KarlBateman That's strange. Did you use the code exactly as I've written it? It seems to work here: https://jsfiddle.net/xqpto7tz/

Comment: What's weird, is where you call `dl`, I have to use `dl()` otherwise it just displays `Awaiting file ..`. It's just a copy and paste, with the url changed.

Comment: @KarlBateman That should definitely be `dl`, not `dl()`. `dl()` will cause it to be re-called immediately and that would also explain why you are getting `undefined` for the id. I assume you're aware that the function is designed to wait 30 seconds if the file is not returned right away, yes? Have you made sure to wait for 30 seconds to see if it succeeds on the second call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an async utility library such as [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/).

The pattern you are looking for seems to be the [waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) pattern.
This will allow you pass the data you need from one task to another.

```
function requestFile(cb){
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'some_url',
        headers: {
           'User-Agent': 'Scripted-Download'
        },
        encoding: null,
        jar: true
    }, function(err, res, body) {
       if (err) throw(err)
       if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/zip;charset=utf-8') {
           process.stdout.write('\rDownloading file ..');
           cb(null, body);
       }
       else{ 
           process.stdout.write('\rAwaiting file ..');
           setTimeout(requestFile, 30 * 1000)
       }
   });
}


function saveFile(body, cb){
    var id = uuid.v4()
      , file = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../' + id + '.zip')
    fs.writeFile(file, body, function(err) {
        if (err) throw(err)
        process.stdout.write('\rFile downloaded ' + id + '.zip');
        cb(null, id);
    })
}

function render(id, cb) {
   //do what ever you need with your id
   cb();
}   

async.waterfall([
    requestFile,
    saveFile,
    render
], function(err){

});
```

BTW, I recommend you stream the data from the server straight to disk rather than collecting it all in a buffer and then saving it.

You can create `data` listeners on the request object and then stream them directly to disk or even just use `request.pipe(file)`

Example:

```
function streamFile(){

    var id = uuid.v4()
        , file = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../' + id + '.zip');
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(file);
    stream.on('error', function(err){
        throw err;
    }).on('close', function(){
        process.stdout.write('\rFile downloaded ' + id + '.zip')
    });

    request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'some_url',
        headers: {
           'User-Agent': 'Scripted-Download'
        },
        encoding: null,
        jar: true
    }).on('error', function(err) {
        throw(err)
    }).on('response', function(res){
        if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/zip;charset=utf-8') {
            process.stdout.write('\rDownloading file ..');
            cb(null, body);
        }
        else{
            process.stdout.write('\rAwaiting file ..');
            res.destroy();
            setTimeout(streamFile, 30 * 1000)
        }
    }).pipe(stream);
}
```

Comment: I guess the issue here is the `setTimeout()` because I can't return a value from this function or use a callback.

Comment: what is `aspectDownload` function

Comment: Yes I would like to stream, but not sure how I would go about doing it, given the structure of the code.

Comment: i've added an example. its not tested but that's the idea!!